# Create user with Auth and write to Firestore at the same time

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I have a scenario where I need to create a user using the `Auth` and add more info (such as name and type of business) to Firestore database. Firestore as transaction/batch operation but it is for Firestore only.

Is there a way where I can perform `Auth` operation such as create along with the Firestore data insert. Both operation has to succeed or fail. Right now I chain them but I would be worried that one fails and the other success in which a will need to handle gracefully.

Thank you

Comment: Do you know how sessions work? You first authenticate the user, then do all operations until the user logs out. You only need to insert the data after authentication.

Comment: At this point  I am not authenticating, I am creating brand new user

Comment: Ok. So create the user, then authenticate, then insert data

Comment: When you create a user, he is being authenticated at the same time. Next I create data. That's what I am doing. The issue here is that if he gets created/authenticated and the data creation fail. I don't want to go through the process of removing the user. That's why I was hoping there is a way I can do "batch" work in one call

Comment: Ah. I think what you are looking for is cloud functions. Refer to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions)

Comment: AHH ok.Thank you so much. If you put it as answer with perhaps code or example (for others as well) then I will accept it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you are implementing Firebase authentication you can use a `addOnCompleteListener` or `addOnSuccessListener` and implement either the `isComplete()` or `isSuccessful()` methods. Inside one of these methods you need to create the user in your Firestore database. With other words, you will create the user only if the authentication is successful. So if `isSuccessful()` either all of the operations beneath one of that methods succeed, or none of them are applied.

The difference between those 2 methods is that we can that a Task is `complete` when the work represented by that Task is finished, regardless of its success or failure. There may be or may be not an error but we need to check for that. A Task is `successful` when the work represented by the task is finished, as expected, with no errors.

As o conclusion, there is no way to have a bulk solution. This is because there are 2 separate operations. So in order to be able to write user details in the database you need to be first successfully authenticated. If you want a rollback then you need to use again an addOnCompleteListener when you write user details to the database. If the you get an error just sin-out the user. There is no transaction/batch operation that can handle authentication and a database write operation as you described.

**Edit:**

Since you say you are using Firebase authentication, you can also use a function, written in Cloud Function to reach your goal. You can write a function that will run every time something in your project happens. One of those "things", is the [creation of an user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events). With other words, you can execute your logic every time a new user is created. Here's an example:

```
exports.updateUserCount = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  //Do what you need to do
});
```

Also, you can do the same thing on a user deletion, but registering a function using `onDelete()` method.

This will be very fast because there is no interaction with user's device. Please see more information about [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

Comment: Hello Alex, thank you but that does not answer the question. Like I said in the question , I am looking for alternative to chaining them like you did. You solution is valid if the addition to firestore works.my concern is what if auth operation was successfull but adding to firestore failed? That's the problem as I need to rollback the whole operation. So I was hoping for bulk solution where either they both succeed or error

Comment: There is no way to have a bulk solution. This is because there are 2 separate operations. So in order to be able to write user details in the database you need to be first successfully authenticated. If you want a rollback then you need to use again an `addOnCompleteListener` when you write user details to the database. If the you get an error just sin-out the user. There is no transaction/batch operation that can handle authentication and a database write operation as you described.

Comment: Thank you. Alright if you put it as an answer then I will accept it

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do scenarios like this is to use `Firebase Cloud Functions`. Cloud functions are triggered on various create/update/delete/write operations. You can trigger a cloud function on new user creation and then do the related `Auth` creation inside it.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions

So in this case, you create user data first and in its success, call the Firebase Auth user creation. If you are worried about failure scenarios, you can remove the created user if in case the auth creation fails.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem by using cloud function to create both auth user and firestore document. This way you can easily have some additional data required to create your user like invite code or things like that.

```
export const signUp = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const email = data.email;
    const password = data.password;
    const firstName = data.firstName;
    const lastName = data.lastName;
    const inviteCode = data.inviteCode;

    const userRecord = await admin.auth().createUser({
        email: email,
        displayName: (firstName && lastName) ? (firstName + ' ' + lastName) : (firstName ?? lastName),
        password: password
    });

    await admin.firestore().collection(constants.COLL_USERS).doc(userRecord.uid).set({
        inviteCode: inviteCode
    })
});
```

Comment: This solution don't work. These promises aren't  are not atomic. The `admin.auth().createUser`  call may work and the write in the Firestore don't, resulting in a user created without NO document written in the Firestore.

Answer (score -1):

If on the same time you want to do authentication and also want to save other details in the FireStore, then you can also do in this way.

if let email = emailTextfield.text ,let password = passwordTextfield.text, let sendername = nameTextField.text {

```
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in

            if let e = error {
                self.showAlert(e.localizedDescription)
            }
            else{

                self.db.collection(K.FStore.registeredDetails).addDocument(data: [K.FStore.registeredName : sendername,
                                                                                  K.FStore.registeredEmail : self.emailTextfield.text!
                ])

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: K.registerSegue, sender: self)
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: What if app crash, or connection disconnect in the middle of the process?